# Given a table of range values how can I scan through this to come up with a grade?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure used to mark tests. Before I do the marking I first find out the grade levels like this:

```
SELECT Grade.Name,
       Grade.Pass,
       Grade.Value
FROM        AdminTest
INNER JOIN  UserTest
ON      AdminTest.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId
INNER JOIN  Grade
ON      AdminTest.AdminTestId = Grade.AdminTestId 
WHERE       UserTest.UserTestId = @UserTestId

Name       Pass  Value
---------- ----- -----------
A          1     80
B          1     50
C          0     25
D          0      0
```

I have numbers that represent the total number of questions, the correct and incorrect:

```
DECLARE @Answers              INT = 30
DECLARE @CorrectAnswers       INT = 20
DECLARE @IncorrectAnswers     INT = 10

DECLARE @Percentage = ( @CorrectAnswers / @Answers ) * 100;
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could use the @Percentage and the grade values that I got from my select and use that to come up with a @FinalGrade

What I need to do is to take @Percentage and somehow match that up in to in this example come up with a grade of 'B'.

I would really like a set based approach but I am not sure if that's possible so maybe using a cursor would be a solution.

I hope someone can give me some hints on what I should do.

Comment: You can use CASE statement. If @percentage= 80 then Grade ='A' similarly for other grades.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I think it would be good but the problem is that the grade tables are not fixed.  One test might have one set of grade tables and the other might have another. That's why I do the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the biggest grade whose min value is less than your current percentage like this:

```
select top 1 @FinalGrade = Name 
from Grade
where Value <= @Percentage
order by Value desc
```

Be careful though: instead of

```
DECLARE @Percentage = ( @CorrectAnswers / @Answers ) * 100;
```

you will need to do either:

```
DECLARE @Percentage = ( convert(float, @CorrectAnswers) / @Answers ) * 100;
```

or:

```
DECLARE @Percentage = @CorrectAnswers * 100 / @Answers;
```

That's because `@CorrectAnswers` and `@Answers` are integers, and using your current expression, you'll get an integer division between them (ex: `10 / 30 * 100` will be `0`).

---

**EDIT:**

The combined `select` should be similar to this:

```
SELECT top 1 
    @FinalGrade = Grade.Name
FROM        AdminTest
INNER JOIN  UserTest
ON      AdminTest.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId
INNER JOIN  Grade
ON      AdminTest.AdminTestId = Grade.AdminTestId 
WHERE   UserTest.UserTestId = @UserTestId
and     Grade.Value <= @Percentage
order by Grade.Value desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the very good suggestion. I didn't realize my percentage calc was not the best way and your other suggestion looks good.  Regarding selecting from Grade. Should I make this a temp table or something? Right now I don't have a grade table. The grade details were just from my select.  How do you think it would be best to do this.  A temp table or can I combine your answer with the select ?

Comment: @Marilou Sorry - I thought that was a `grade` table ready to use. In your case, I'd avoid the temp table and simply mix the two `SELECTs`.

Comment: @Marilou Please see the edit to my question; I added a combined `select` statement.